# Under to access css file in another folder

Tags: html, css

I have 2 folders, 1 named template where my index.html is. The other is named static where my main.css file is. I used the following code to access my css file from index.html but i got a 404 error. I'm using google app engine in python.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/main.css" type="text/css">
```

Comment: without more details we can't know anything. Please, read the FAQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these folders are at the application root you could try using a url like below.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/main.css" type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 0):

try giving full path e.g
C:\xampp\htdocs\yourFolder\static\main.css